# WOFF based fonts are not working in Firefox, but fine in other browsers

Tags: css, fonts, truetype, woff, eot

http://thereferraladvantage.com/preview/

CSS in base.css:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'gotham';
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url('../fonts/gotham_light.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('../fonts/gotham_light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/gotham_light.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/gotham_light.ttf')  format('truetype') /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       ;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'gotham';
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url('../fonts/gotham_book.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('../fonts/gotham_book.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/gotham_book.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/gotham_book.ttf')  format('truetype') /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       ;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'gotham';
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: italic;
  src: url('../fonts/gotham_bookitalic.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('../fonts/gotham_bookitalic.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/gotham_bookitalic.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/gotham_bookitalic.ttf')  format('truetype') /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       ;
}


@font-face {
  font-family: 'gotham';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: url('../fonts/gotham_medium.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('../fonts/gotham_medium.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/gotham_medium.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/gotham_medium.ttf')  format('truetype') /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       ;
}



@font-face {
  font-family: 'gotham';
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: italic;
  src: url('../fonts/gotham_mediumitalic.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('../fonts/gotham_mediumitalic.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/gotham_mediumitalic.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/gotham_mediumitalic.ttf')  format('truetype') /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       ;
}
```

Firebug shows that the browser is calling both woff and tff files, with status 200 (OK) for both files. It concerns me, shouldn't it be calling just the WOFF, rather than reverting to TTF?

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question. Cross-origin embed was the issue. The .css file was called with the www., I was opening the site without the www. This is why I always put the .htaccess line that forces www. to be added if missing, just a good practice. Except I missed it on this one because I hadn't launched it yet and I was just testing & tinkering around.